# what's the purpose of WebViewClient.onLoadResource

Tags: android, android-webview

I would like to ask the purpose the

```
WebViewClient.onLoadResource
```

even we can get this callback when webkit tries to load resource
but since its return type is void

what can we anything in this function???

I know in API 11 there's a shouldInterceptResouce 
but how about for those froyo/gingerbread devices?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> Notify the host application that the WebView will load the resource specified by the given url.

So, you can override it in your implementation of WebViewClient, for example, to cache resources for future use in your application.